# ADO.NET - Insert using Adapter.Update() with a subset of columns from Parent Table

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ado.net

I have a adapter like this -

```
var ds = new DataSet("T1");
adapter.Fill(ds, "Table1");
```

Now, Table1 has 3 columns - Col1, Col2, Col3

I have a Table 2 with Col1 and Col3. How can I use the above adapter to Insert records for **only** *selected* columns from Table1 into Table2 ? I tried this, but no luck.

```
// remove the column which is not required
ds.Tables["Table1"].Columns.Remove("Col2");

// clear the old table mappings
adapter.TableMappings.Clear();

// create new table mappings
DataTableMapping mapping = adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table2", ds.Tables["Table1"].ToString());
mapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Col1", ds.Tables["Table1"].Columns[0].ColumnName);
mapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Col3", ds.Tables["Table1"].Columns[2].ColumnName);

// fill the adapter with new Dataset
var newDs = ds.Copy();
adapter.Fill(newDs);
ds.Dispose();

// Insert records into new Table
recordsUpdated += adapter.Update(newDs , "Table2");
```

**ERROR - Additional information: Missing the DataColumn 'Col2' in the DataTable 'Table1' for the SourceColumn 'Col2'.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this -

a.Initialise a SqlDataAdapter with the new Table (SELECT * FROM Table2) - call it

```
newAdapter
```

> Make sure you make - ***AcceptChangesDuringFill = false*** because, later,
>   while enumerating rows, setting the rowstate to added will not work
>   otherwise.

b.Remove the unwanted column from the data table of Table1

c.Update the row state of this data table to 'Added' like this -

```
// 1st, commit all changes in the DataTable.
dtTable1.AcceptChanges();

// update the row state
foreach (DataRow row in dtTable1.Rows)
{
  row.SetAdded();
}
```

d.Finally 'insert' using the adapter created in Step a. like this -

```
var recordsInserted = newAdapter.Update(dtTable1); // insert happens
```